# getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3 while deleting items from firebaseui recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have a list of items that I am retrieving from Firebase. To delete those items I have implemented a delete button. I am trying to get the post key after the user clicks the delete button. Currently I am able to delete items, but when I delete something from the middle of the RecyclerView and then and then the first item, the app crashes.

Code:

```
public class MyPosts extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MyPosts";

    Toolbar toolbar;
    DatabaseReference WorkingData;
    DatabaseReference WorkingDataForDeletion;
    DatabaseReference tasks;

    private BottomNavigationView navigationView;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<WorkInformation> workList;

    private AppCompatButton deletePost;
    private AppCompatButton editPost;
    String currentUserID, postKey;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_posts);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_post_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Posts");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        currentUserID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        WorkingData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserIndividualTasks");
        WorkingData.keepSynced(true);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_post_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        deletePost = findViewById(R.id.myPostDelete);
        editPost = findViewById(R.id.myPostEdit);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Query query = WorkingData.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<WorkInformation> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<WorkInformation>()
                .setQuery(query, WorkInformation.class)
                .build();


        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WorkInformation, MyViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WorkInformation, MyViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull WorkInformation model) {


                holder.title.setText(model.getWorkTitle());
                holder.date.setText(model.getWorkDueDate());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getImg()).into(holder.imageView);


                holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        postKey = getRef(position).getKey();


                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: position is " + position);

                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: post key is " + postKey);

                        notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        WorkingDataForDeletion = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserIndividualTasks")
                                .child(currentUserID)
                                .child(postKey);
                        WorkingDataForDeletion.removeValue();



                        notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_posts_individual_row_layout, parent, false);
                MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public AppCompatTextView title;
        public AppCompatTextView date;
        public CircleImageView imageView;
        public AppCompatButton deleteBtn;
        public AppCompatButton editBtn;
        public ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_posts_title);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myPostDate);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.UserImage);
            deleteBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myPostDelete);
            editBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myPostEdit);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                startActivity(new Intent(MyPosts.this, Services.class));
                break;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void deleteUserPost() {

    }

}
```

Crash log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.saqib.smarttaskk, PID: 19583
              java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
                  at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.getSnapshot(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:70)
                  at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:112)
                  at com.example.saqib.smarttaskk.MyPosts$1$1.onClick(MyPosts.java:131)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891)
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't ever use `position` inside of listeners or asynchronous tasks.

Inside your `OnClickListener`, replace any use of `position` with `holder.getAdapterPosition()`.

You should also remove *all* calls to any sort of data notification (`notifyDataSetChanged()`, `notifyItemRemoved()`, etc), inside or outside your adapter.

Your final `onClick()` method should look like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    //removed notifyDataSetChanged()
    postKey = getRef(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey();

    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: position is " + holder.getAdapterPosition());

    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: post key is " + postKey);

    //removed notifyItemRemoved()

    //variable names should be camelCase not TitleCase
    workingDataForDeletion = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserIndividualTasks")
            .child(currentUserID)
            .child(postKey);
    workingDataForDeletion.removeValue();

    //removed notifyItemRemoved()
    //removed notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: cannot delete even a single post now :/...                  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{8b2940 position=-1 id=-1, oldPos=1, pLpos:0 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{8f0ff30 VFED..... .F.....D 0,0-1080,1836 #7f0800ca app:id/my_post_recycler_view}, adapter:com.example.saqib.smarttaskk.MyPosts$1@b7d77a9, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@497a12e, context:com.example.saqib.smarttaskk.MyPosts@de3d17b

Comment: Remove the calls to `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and remove the `notifyItemRemoved()` as well.

Comment: Why is it not recommended to call these methods inside or outside the adapter?

Comment: Any suggestion/alternative to update/notify our data adapter? @TheWanderer

Comment: [this](https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-inconsistency-detected-invalid-item-position-android-recyclerview/) post says, we need to to call `getRecycledViewPool().clear()` before any `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`, also check the RV `itemCount` when doing any `notifyItem*`

Comment: @mochadwi the OP is using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, which calls those methods itself.

Answer (score 0):

**use this**

```
        product_list.remove(product_list.get(position))
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemCount)
```